wha is spring ERROR 11044 that happens during ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext?
I'm getting this annoying error, error 11044 in spring, couldn't find any info about it, this is the message:
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service': Error creating bean with name 'service': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository': Error creating bean with name 'repository' defined in br.com.example.spring_boot_and_kotlin.repository.Repository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class br.com.example.spring_boot_and_kotlin.model.Person
I've been banging my head against the wall here for hours, i've checked for missing annotations, tried some annotations for scanning beans, but nothing seems to be effective, The problem started to happen after I tried a PersonDTO mapping.
could someone enlighten me here?
Thank you in advanced!!

To give a precise answer, you'd need to provide the relevant source code (which I would have told you in a comment, if Stackoverflow would allow me to write a comment with my current level of reputation...).
From what I can see from the stacktrace, you have a class Controller that has a reference to a Service which has a reference to Repository, which seams to be dealing with Persons and is complaining that br.com.example.spring_boot_and_kotlin.model.Person is not a managed type.
I guess it is missing an @Entity annotation or something like that, but as said, a precise answer would require the relevant source code.

The problem was that I was converting an entity into a DTO and using dozer for that, and I made something wrong through this process, I've solved it by going back some steps and implementing it again, and it seemed to work well, I don't know exaclty what went worng though, but it's working hahahahaha
